# Problema al ejecutar Code::blocks no inicia!

Tags: codeblocks

Reinstalé Code::Blocks en mi computadora debido a que hace unos días comenzó a fallar de una manera muy extraña, pues lo abría y no aparecía, es decir, no se mostraba la interfaz, y al abrir el administrador de tareas se mostraba en ejecución y en la barra de tareas aparece; y al seleccionarlo no muestra más que la aplicación anterior, pero aún así el problema sigue vigente.

Intente reinstalar Codeblocks sin exito!

Dejo dos captura de pantalla para ser más específico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que inicia y se cierra? Agrega más datos a tu pregunta, que ¿sistema operativo? , ¿Realizaste instalación de algo más?, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: Pensaba poner una captura de pantalla para mostrar el problema, pero no lo hice debido a un problema con otra pregunta que hice aquí, pero como dices, tendré que ser muy explicativo.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de problema? Considero es bueno agregar una imagen, siempre y cuando no sea imagen de codigo. Agrega tu imagen y aporta mas detalles :).

Comment: Por supuesto :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto mi experiencia, a mi me ha sucedido lo mismo un par de ocasiones, me parece que es un cambio en la configuración, este problema persiste aún reinstalando la aplicación.

Una solución es buscar el archivo de configuración de Code Blocks el cual esta ubicado en :

```
C:\Users\ <USUARIO> \AppData\Roaming\CodeBlocks
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y renombrarlo o eliminarlo para que reinicies la configuración y de esta forma inicie sin problemas!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! En verdad funcionó y lo abre. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo. Ahora sí podré trabajar bien en C++

Comment: @EmmanCanVaz_95 un placer amigo, saludos!